# How to rewrite this totient summation in terms of Mertens?

Tags: nt.number-theory

The totient sum function has an identity:

$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N}\varphi(k) = \sum_{k=1}^N {\rm M}(\lfloor\frac{N}{k}\rfloor)k $

$\varphi(k)$ is the Euler totient function, and $M$ is the Mertens function $\displaystyle M(N)=\sum_{k=1}^N \mu (k)$ where $\mu$ is the Moebius function.

My question: What is the Mertens function summation equivalent of $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N}k\varphi(k) $ and $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{N}k^2\varphi(k)$?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316376/how-to-calculate-these-totient-summation-sums-efficiently   and   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317482/how-to-rewrite-this-totient-summation-in-terms-of-mertens  the latter deleted a few minutes ago.

Comment: @WillJagy Yes, that was my question. It had not been getting much response.

Comment: Why do you think there is anything to be said about this? And what are you doing?

Comment: Why why why why do you refuse, despite repeated urging, to link your questions to your earlier, related questions? Why does someone else always have to do this for you? 

Comment: @GerryMyerson I spoke with joriki about it; won't happen again. Sorry for not linking the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\varphi(n)=n\sum_{d|n}\frac{\mu(d)}{d},$  by switching the order of summation we have that for fixed $l$  $$\sum_{n\leq x}\varphi(n)n^{l}=\sum_{kd\leq x}\mu(d)k^{l}d^{l}k$$

$$=\sum_{k\leq x}k^{l+1}\sum_{d\leq\frac{x}{d}}\mu(d)d^{l}.$$ Now, $$\sum_{d\leq y}\mu(d)d^{l}=\int_{0}^{y}t^{l}d\left(M(t)\right)=M(y)y^{l}-l\int_{0}^{y}M(t)t^{l-1}dt,$$ so you can write  $$\sum_{n\leq x}\varphi(n)n^{l}=\sum_{k\leq x}k^{l+1}\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)^{l}M\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)-l\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{k}}t^{l-1}M(t)dt.$$ This may be rearranged as

$$x^{l}\sum_{k\leq x}kM\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)-l\sum_{k\leq x}k^{l+1}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{k}}t^{l-1}M(t)dt,$$ which is equal to

$$x^{l}\sum_{k\leq x}kM\left(\frac{x}{k}\right)-l\int_{0}^{x}t^{l-1}\sum_{k\leq x}k^{2}M\left(\frac{t}{k}\right)dt.$$

Comment: Does this not have arithmetic closed forms like the l=0 case?

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317482/how-to-rewrite-this-totient-summation-in-terms-of-mertens  

Comment: When $l=0$ you obtain the result at the displayed equation in my answer above.

Comment: @Will Jagy: I didn't see the question on Math Stack Exchange until after answering this.

Comment: @EricNaslund I will accept this as the answer but I am honestly not sure how to use it. Taking the integral of a summation of a Merten function seems like a far stretch more complex than the simple closed-form for the l=0 case.

Comment: @EricNaslund Are there closed-forms for the l=1 and l=2 cases that don't require the integral?

Comment: Eric, please see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/317635/how-to-evaluate-this-integral-involving-mertens 

Comment: @EricNaslund Also, forgive me if I am wrong but I believe there is an error in the second line where it says $\sum_{d\leq\frac{x}{d}}\mu(d)d^{l}$. I think it should be $\sum_{d\leq\frac{x}{k}}\mu(d)d^{l}$